# Perform file via web JNLP saved in the user's machine

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I have a web system where downloading a PDF to the user's machine is done. Since this file should be printed only once developed a Java Web Start that takes care of sending the PDF to the printer and then delete the file. So far everything is working well, my site downloads the JNLP and I run and it prints.

Need help to solve this problem:
I will leave this JNLP saved on the user's desktop for example in C://JNLP/, and need it to be called from the web page.  I do not want to download each time you print, and that the user does not give-click the JNLP, wanted to call it via code. It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can install your Web Start application on user's machine. Try this in your JNLP file:

```
  <information>
    ...
    <offline-allowed/> 
    <shortcut online="true" install="true">
      <desktop/>
      <menu submenu="My Apps"/>
    </shortcut>
  </information>
```

During a click on your page you can generate a JNLP file where PDF to print is defined as property or application argument. Your app should now start faster, and user can also run it using desktop / menu shortcut.